# PDFClown Detect empty text location

Tags: c#, extractor, pdfclown

I am able to use the PDFClown library in C# to parse and extract the text from a daily report in PDF. The issue I am having is detecting when a text value is missing. Using the TextExtractor, there is no place holder in the text value as I expected. The PDF document has a box where the missing text should be so it would seem like there should be some way to detect value is not there. There is no form in this document.

Comment: I would go with WKHTMLToPDF or ITextSharp over PDFClown personally.

Comment: @David the `TextExtractor` extracts text. A box is not text (well, usually not). Thus, the `TextExtractor` does not extract it.

Comment: The TextExtractor returns a list of Text Strings, one for each line of text in the PDF, with coordinates for a 2D rectangle for the whole line. I could probably do what I need to do if I have the 2D rectangle surrounding each individual text string. I haven't seen a way to get that yet.